# Linq All() / Any() but not empty

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-expressions

I have a Linq expression that is used in a few places. I went down the expression route as there wasn't a logical way to accomplish some searching logic without enumerating a very large table otherwise.

```
    private Expression<Func<Property, bool>> PropertyIsCompliant()
    {
        return (p) => p.CalculationSets.OfType<SingleDocumentCalculationSet>()
            .GroupBy(cs => cs.SourceDocument)
            .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateTime).FirstOrDefault().CalculationResults)
            .SelectMany(cr => cr)
            .All(cr => cr.Outcome == CalculationOutcome.Success);
    }
```

My models are as such:

- A Property has many CalculationSets
- Each CalculationSet is also assigned to a Document
- Each CalculationSet has a number of CalculationResults
- Each CalculationResult has an Outcome

I'm trying to create an expression that will tell me if all the outcomes from the most recent calculationsets grouped by document ordered by most recent (ie the most recent distinct results) are Successful.

I can the SelectMany clause returns all the CalculationResults from the correct CalculationSets.
I just cant figure out how to return true ONLY if the collection isn't empty AND they are all Outcome.Success.

I understand the All operator automatically returns true on an empty collection. I just can't think of a way around it!

Answer (score 3):

So your *real* condition is that there are *not any* unsuccessful outcomes.  In that case use `Any` and reverse the condition:

```
                //V-- notice the ! inverse operator here
    return (p) => !(p.CalculationSets.OfType<SingleDocumentCalculationSet>()
        .GroupBy(cs => cs.SourceDocument)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateTime).FirstOrDefault().CalculationResults)
        .SelectMany(cr => cr)
        .Any(cr => cr.Outcome != CalculationOutcome.Success));
```

Comment: If there are failures, this will return true although it should return false.

Answer (score 1):

```
var countsBySuccess = 
 ...
 .GroupBy(cr => cr.Outcome == CalculationOutcome.Success) //group on success
 .Select(g => new { IsSuccessful = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

You can now examine the two result rows to make sure that the unsuccessful count is zero and the successful count is non-zero.

Regarding performance, this will need to materialize the entire result set server-side and aggregate it. But it does so only once.

If you must use the calculation result as part of a bigger query, you must use another trick:

```
!countsBySuccess.Any(g =>
    g.IsSuccessful && Count == 0 ||
    !g.IsSuccessful && Count != 0)
```

This boolean expression determines whether the condition you are looking for holds with one scan of the data.

It is important to only scan the data once. Do *not* simply write:

```
myItems.All(cr => cr.Outcome == CalculationOutcome.Success) && myItems.Any()
```

Because that does two scans. SQL Server does not optimize this out.

Comment: The performance issue I was concerned about is pulling all the records from the SQL DB to the application. I'm less concerned about 2 separate scans on the SQL DB it's self. I've gone with a similar solution to your "don't do this" suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're answering your question - if you know that All returns TRUE for empty then you have two checks to make.  Excuse my C# (I'm not sure on the var query assignment, hopefully you get the idea) but you could do something like this:

```
private Expression<Func<Property, bool>> PropertyIsCompliant()
    {
        var query = (p) => p.CalculationSets.OfType<SingleDocumentCalculationSet>()
            .GroupBy(cs => cs.SourceDocument)
            .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateTime).FirstOrDefault().CalculationResults)
            .SelectMany(cr => cr);

        return (query.Count > 0) & query.All(cr => cr.Outcome == CalculationOutcome.Success);
    }
```

Comment: This is not SQL translatable, or if you force it it will be inefficient.

Comment: I used a similar solution (below) that does translate to SQL correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise it was possible to use "&&" in expressions. So I've managed to combine 2 separate expressions that give the answer I need. The "&&" only returns true when both expressions evaluate "true"

```
            return (p) => 
            p.CalculationSets.OfType<SingleDocumentCalculationSet>()
            .GroupBy(cs => cs.SourceDocument)
            .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateTime).FirstOrDefault().CalculationResults)
            .SelectMany(cr => cr).Any()
            &&
            p.CalculationSets.OfType<SingleDocumentCalculationSet>()
            .GroupBy(cs => cs.SourceDocument)
            .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateTime).FirstOrDefault().CalculationResults)
            .SelectMany(cr => cr)
            .All(cr => cr.Outcome == CalculationOutcome.Success);
```

Comment: Wow that's a lot of duplication. I'd prefer my solution, even if I say so myself :)

Comment: It's since changed as the 1st query only needs to check if a CalculationSet exists. So no grouping, ordering, selecting for the 1st query needed.